# Css3 animation - how to keep animation roating in exact place

Tags: html, css, animation

I am working on some basic cog animation using css3,

The problem I have is the cogs are moving around slightly and not staying in one exact spot.

Is it possible to fix the images in one spot so they dont move.

Amy help would be great !!!

Please see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfW9r/)

```
.container{
        background:black;
}
#cog-animation{
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 380px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    }

/* CSS3 keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes ckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes ckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

/* gears */
.gear {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;

    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
#gear1 {
  background: url('http://paulobriendesign.co.uk/images/g1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 58px;
  width: 58px;
  left: 81px;
  top: 25px;
  -moz-animation-name: ckw;
  -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-name: ckw;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  }
#gear2 {
  background: url('http://paulobriendesign.co.uk/images/g2.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 85px;
  left: 143px;
  top: 36px;
  width: 85px;
  -moz-animation-name: cckw;
  -moz-animation-duration: 16.84s;
  -webkit-animation-name: cckw;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 16.84s;
}
#gear3 {
  background: url('http://paulobriendesign.co.uk/images/g3.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  left: 218px;
  top: 11px;
  -moz-animation-name: ckw;
  -moz-animation-duration: 13.5s;
  -webkit-animation-name: ckw;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 13.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background images are off center.

Try adding:
background-position:center;

Answer (score 1):

The images aren't perfectly square - g1 is 54x53; g2 is 80x79; g3 is 39x38.

The bigger issue is your divs are bigger than your background images. `#gear1` is 58x58, but the image is only 54x53, so there is some extra space which makes it look like the gear is moving when the div rotates.